# User-Function, formals object defined but not found by code

Tags: r, function, arguments, argument-passing

The business I work for does ELISA analysis all the time (the immune assay), and so I am programming a function that takes a csv format version of the machine readout for the optical densities and runs a statistical regression called a 4PL analysis. It is essentially a 4pl for dummies function that makes use of the drc package. I have most of the code written, but now I am attempting to actually put it IN to a function format (it runs fine outside of function structure).

Here is my problem. I am defining the formals() of my function like so:

```
elisa<-function(file="data.csv",wd="~/Desktop",standards=c(1,2),orient=horizontal,
limit=TRUE,graph.4pl=FALSE,Conc.graph=FALSE){ body of function}
```

It's not particularly important what the other formals are at the moment, but I am running into two problems. Here is the code for the first part of the block.

```
rm(list=ls())
setwd(wd)
library(drc);library(reshape2);library(ggplot2)

data<-read.csv(file,head=TRUE, colClasses=c("character"))
```

If the community in its wisdom thinks I need to include more, I will, but let's leave it there for now.

The problem:

```
elisa("Mock data.csv")
Error in setwd(wd[1]) : object 'wd' not found
```

This error shows up. As you can see though, wd IS defined

```
formals(elisa)
$file
[1] "data.csv"

$wd
[1] "~/Desktop"

$standards
c(1, 2)

$orient
horizontal

$limit
[1] TRUE

$graph.4pl
[1] FALSE

$Conc.graph
[1] FALSE
```

Moreover, if I predefine wd as `"~/Desktop"` in the global environment, the error for wd goes away, but I get this

```
wd<-"~/Desktop"
elisa("Mock data.csv")
Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
 'file' must be a character string or connection
```

Either I am completely tanking on how I am defining my formals, or I am running into some very odd argument passing issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not include the path in the `file` argument? Also, I doubt it's an issue you're seeing, but does `horizontal` need to be a character string?

Comment: You're right. Once I got the main issue resolved, horizontal being treated as an object rather than a string was the next bug identified :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you're deleting all of your formals with the first line, `rm(list=ls())`.

For example:

```
f <- function(a=1) {
  rm(list=ls())
  print(a)
}
f()
## Error in print(a) : object 'a' not found
```

When you define `wd` in the global environment (i.e. in the stack above your function) your function will work (at least up until that point) because `rm(list=ls())` will only delete the variables within your current environment (i.e. the function call stack). In this case, your function will use values for variables defined in the global environment.

Comment: Omg, I'm a moron. I had that in the code when I was rapidly iterating to debug when it wasn't a function, and I forgot to yank it when I strung it all together. I got so focused on there probably being a direct cause between the formals and the setwd command that I completely forgot to check for interference from other lines. Please excuse my battle-blindness. This is just embarrassing. Thank you for being my second set of eyes.